# Not a Valid month statement in oracle while querying

Tags: oracle

I need a help in fixing the 'Not a Valid Month' statement and below the query is working perfectly with MAX function..

```
SELECT MAX( Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME ) FROM ADPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT Y WHERE Y.FILE_EVENT_TYPE = 'SUBMISSION' AND 
   Y.FILE_SUBMT_RETRL_STATUS = 'LEVEL1 POSTED' AND Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME >= '01-DEC-2015' AND Y.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME <= '03-FEB-2017'
GROUP BY Y.WR_FILE_TRANS_INFO_ID
```

And output is as followed...

```
12/11/2015 1:44:33 PM
2/2/2017 3:42:02 PM
2/2/2017 3:42:02 PM
```

Now i need to rewrite the query without MAX function and these are the queries i prepared below. But both display 'Not a valid Month' statement..

```
SELECT X.WR_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT_ID FROM ADPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT X WHERE X.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME IN
 ('20170202034202','20170202034202','20151211014433')

 SELECT X.WR_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT_ID FROM ADPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT X WHERE X.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME IN
 ('2017-02-02 03:42:02.0','2017-02-02 03:42:02.0','2015-12-11 01:44:33.0')
```

Can you help me to get rid of this error please...

Comment: Please show the table definition of X.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME

Comment: FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP(6)  04-APR-17

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag for Oracle questions, only for MySQL questions.

Comment: Sure Barmar and i wll do that going forward..

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in your date format.  For date columns, Oracle will try to convert to a date based on NLS default settings.  For your SQL, let's be more specific and tell Oracle exactly how to interpret the date string, like...

(assuming a DATE data type)

```
SELECT X.WR_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT_ID 
FROM ADPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT X 
WHERE X.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME IN
      (TO_DATE('2017-02-02 03:42:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TO_DATE('2017-02-02 03:42:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TO_DATE('2015-12-11 01:44:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
      );
```

..or as I just saw your comment on the TIMESTAMP column

```
SELECT X.WR_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT_ID 
FROM ADPDBA.WORK_REQUEST_FILE_TRANS_AUDIT X 
WHERE X.FILE_SUB_RET_DATE_TIME IN
      (TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017-02-02 03:42:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017-02-02 03:42:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
       TO_TIMESTAMP ('2015-12-11 01:44:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
      );
```

Comment: Mine is Timestamp and tried with Time stamp and Its not fetching any records ...and the db records show with AM/PM  like below 12/11/2015 1:44:33 PM
2/2/2017 3:42:02 PM
2/2/2017 3:42:02 PM

Comment: @RamKarlapudi as it is `pm` not `am` the following timestamps should work `TO_TIMESTAMP ('2015-12-11 13:44:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` ,`TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017-02-02 15:42:02', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`...